# Fulfilling pdf template using vba - problem choice list

Tags: javascript, xml, vba, pdf

I have a macro, which fulfills PDF template using VBA code. Everything works fine with ordinary field, but i have a little problem with choicelist - depending on choice from choicelist there are some changes in PDF template, but when i try to change value of this field (using Fields("nameoffield").value=) it doesn't changes anything in template - how i can execute it from VBA level?

Here is partial code of this choicelist

```
    <field name="fieldname">

            <event activity="exit" name="event__exit">
               <script contentType="application/x-javascript">var val = this.rawValue;

if(val == 1){
  ‘sth
}else if(val == 2){
   ‘sth
}else if(val == 3){
   ‘sth
}else if(val == 4){
  ‘sth   
}else{
    this.rawValue = this.rawValue;
}
</script>
            </event>
            <items>
               <text>Choice1</text>
               <text>Choice2</text>
               <text>Choice3</text>
               <text>Choice4</text>
            </items>
            <items save="1" presence="hidden">
               <text>1</text>
               <text>2</text>
               <text>3</text>
               <text>4</text>
            </items>

            <value>
               <text>2</text>
            </value>

      </field>
```

Comment: this looks like C#. if so please edit tags accordingly

Comment: It's XML code of pdf template, with partial Javascript